# How to translate multiple strings from the list with using dictionaries

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary, bioinformatics

I am trying to translate all the Open reading frames (ORFs) into amino acid sequences using aa_dict in python, and wondering how can I go over every string in my list and translate them. I appreciate your help, thank you!

long_ORFs list is something like this:

```
['ATGAGAGAG', 'AGAGAAGTCT', 'ACACTAGAGAGAGA',......]
```

and here is my code:

```
def translate(long_ORFs):


     aa_dict = {
    'AAA': 'K',  'AAC': 'N',  'AAG': 'K',  'AAT': 'N',  'ACA': 'T',  'ACC': 'T',  
    'ACG': 'T',  'ACT': 'T',  'AGA': 'R',  'AGC': 'S',  'AGG': 'R',  'AGT': 'S',  
    'ATA': 'I',  'ATC': 'I',  'ATG': 'M',  'ATT': 'I',  'CAA': 'Q',  'CAC': 'H',  
    'CAG': 'Q',  'CAT': 'H',  'CCA': 'P',  'CCC': 'P',  'CCG': 'P',  'CCT': 'P',  
    'CGA': 'R',  'CGC': 'R',  'CGG': 'R',  'CGT': 'R',  'CTA': 'L',  'CTC': 'L',  
    'CTG': 'L',  'CTT': 'L',  'GAA': 'E',  'GAC': 'D',  'GAG': 'E',  'GAT': 'D',  
    'GCA': 'A',  'GCC': 'A',  'GCG': 'A',  'GCT': 'A',  'GGA': 'G',  'GGC': 'G',  
    'GGG': 'G',  'GGT': 'G',  'GTA': 'V',  'GTC': 'V',  'GTG': 'V',  'GTT': 'V',  
    'TAA': '*',  'TAC': 'Y',  'TAG': '*',  'TAT': 'Y',  'TCA': 'S',  'TCC': 'S',  
    'TCG': 'S',  'TCT': 'S',  'TGA': '*',  'TGC': 'C',  'TGG': 'W',  'TGT': 'C',  
    'TTA': 'L',  'TTC': 'F',  'TTG': 'L',  'TTT': 'F'  
}
     aaList = [] # an empty list

     if len(long_ORFs) % 3 ==0:


         for i in range(0, len(long_ORFs), 3):

              codon = long_ORFs [ i : i+3]

              aaList += aa_dict[codon]
              
              
     return ''.join(aaList)

translate(long_ORFs)
```

this resulted as an empty string

Comment: IIUC, you want to translate each of the sequences in long_ORF not long_ORF itself.  Also, the sequence lengths in your example i.e. `['ATGAGAGAG', 'AGAGAAGTCT', 'ACACTAGAGAGAGA']`, are 9, 10, and 14 (thus only the first is a multiple of 3).

Comment: Thanks for your response! These sequences are just an example, but eventually yes, I want to translate each sequence in the list, and that's I don't know how to. I wanted to splice it by 3 to get the codons in each sequence to be translated.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:-**

```
def translate(long_ORFs):
    aa_dict = {'AAA': 'K',  'AAC': 'N',  'AAG': 'K',  'AAT': 'N',  'ACA': 'T',  'ACC': 'T',  'ACG': 'T',  'ACT': 'T',  'AGA': 'R',  'AGC': 'S',  'AGG': 'R',  'AGT': 'S',  'ATA': 'I',  'ATC': 'I',  'ATG': 'M',  'ATT': 'I',  'CAA': 'Q',  'CAC': 'H',  'CAG': 'Q',  'CAT': 'H',  'CCA': 'P',  'CCC': 'P',  'CCG': 'P',  'CCT': 'P',  'CGA': 'R',  'CGC': 'R',  'CGG': 'R',  'CGT': 'R',  'CTA': 'L',  'CTC': 'L',  'CTG': 'L',  'CTT': 'L',  'GAA': 'E',  'GAC': 'D',  'GAG': 'E',  'GAT': 'D',  'GCA': 'A',  'GCC': 'A',  'GCG': 'A',  'GCT': 'A',  'GGA': 'G',  'GGC': 'G',  'GGG': 'G',  'GGT': 'G',  'GTA': 'V',  'GTC': 'V',  'GTG': 'V',  'GTT': 'V',  'TAA': '*',  'TAC': 'Y',  'TAG': '*',  'TAT': 'Y',  'TCA': 'S',  'TCC': 'S',  'TCG': 'S',  'TCT': 'S',  'TGA': '*',  'TGC': 'C',  'TGG': 'W',  'TGT': 'C',  'TTA': 'L',  'TTC': 'F',  'TTG': 'L',  'TTT': 'F'  }
    aaList = [] # an empty list
    for word in long_ORFs:
        if len(word)%3==0:
            temp=""
            for i in range(0, len(word), 3):
                codon=word[i:i+3]
                temp+=aa_dict[codon]
            aaList.append(temp)      
        else:
            continue
    return aaList

print(translate(['ATGAGAGAG','AGAGAAGTC','ACACTAGAGAGAGA']))
```

**Output:-**

```
['MRE', 'REV']
```

These 2 outputs are from first 2 words there is no 3rd output because the **3rd word is not divisble by 3**

Comment: @YaseminDilaraSucu from these 3 answers the best one which helps you.. you can just ✔️ that answer so that fellow members know the best answer for this question...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that rather than processing the contents of `long_ORFs` the way you are, you instead want to iterate over `long_ORFs` and process each item in that list individually.  So I think you want something like this:

```
long_ORFs = ['ATGAGAGAG', 'AGAGAAGTCT', 'ACACTAGAGAGAGA']

def translate(long_ORFs):
    aa_dict = {
        'AAA': 'K', 'AAC': 'N', 'AAG': 'K', 'AAT': 'N', 'ACA': 'T', 'ACC': 'T',
        'ACG': 'T', 'ACT': 'T', 'AGA': 'R', 'AGC': 'S', 'AGG': 'R', 'AGT': 'S',
        'ATA': 'I', 'ATC': 'I', 'ATG': 'M', 'ATT': 'I', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CAC': 'H',
        'CAG': 'Q', 'CAT': 'H', 'CCA': 'P', 'CCC': 'P', 'CCG': 'P', 'CCT': 'P',
        'CGA': 'R', 'CGC': 'R', 'CGG': 'R', 'CGT': 'R', 'CTA': 'L', 'CTC': 'L',
        'CTG': 'L', 'CTT': 'L', 'GAA': 'E', 'GAC': 'D', 'GAG': 'E', 'GAT': 'D',
        'GCA': 'A', 'GCC': 'A', 'GCG': 'A', 'GCT': 'A', 'GGA': 'G', 'GGC': 'G',
        'GGG': 'G', 'GGT': 'G', 'GTA': 'V', 'GTC': 'V', 'GTG': 'V', 'GTT': 'V',
        'TAA': '*', 'TAC': 'Y', 'TAG': '*', 'TAT': 'Y', 'TCA': 'S', 'TCC': 'S',
        'TCG': 'S', 'TCT': 'S', 'TGA': '*', 'TGC': 'C', 'TGG': 'W', 'TGT': 'C',
        'TTA': 'L', 'TTC': 'F', 'TTG': 'L', 'TTT': 'F'
    }
    aaList = []  # an empty list

    for orf in long_ORFs:
        if len(orf) % 3 == 0:
            buf = ''
            for i in range(0, len(orf), 3):
                codon = orf[i: i + 3]
                buf += aa_dict[codon]
            aaList.append(buf)
    return aaList

print(translate(long_ORFs))
```

Result:

```
['MRE']
```

You are only getting a single entry in the resulting list because only one of the three input sequences in `long_ORFs` has a length that is an even multiple of three.  Since you're testing for that, you only process and add that one entry to the final output.  If you move that constraint into the inner loop and just ignore extra characters that aren't part of a group of 3 characters, like this:

```
for orf in long_ORFs:
    buf = ''
    for i in range(0, len(orf), 3):
        codon = orf[i: i + 3]
        if len(codon) == 3:
            buf += aa_dict[codon]
    aaList.append(buf)
```

Then you get the result:

```
['MRE', 'REV', 'TLER']
```

Comment: @DarrylG - no, `codon` isn't a list...it's a string, because `orf` is a string, and so `orf[i: i + 3]` is a slice of that string.

Comment: You're right.  My error was from the posted code where codon there is a list.  But, that code is incorrect since its looping over long_ORF.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

aa_dict = {
    'AAA': 'K', 'AAC': 'N', 'AAG': 'K', 'AAT': 'N', 'ACA': 'T', 'ACC': 'T',
    'ACG': 'T', 'ACT': 'T', 'AGA': 'R', 'AGC': 'S', 'AGG': 'R', 'AGT': 'S',
    'ATA': 'I', 'ATC': 'I', 'ATG': 'M', 'ATT': 'I', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CAC': 'H',
    'CAG': 'Q', 'CAT': 'H', 'CCA': 'P', 'CCC': 'P', 'CCG': 'P', 'CCT': 'P',
    'CGA': 'R', 'CGC': 'R', 'CGG': 'R', 'CGT': 'R', 'CTA': 'L', 'CTC': 'L',
    'CTG': 'L', 'CTT': 'L', 'GAA': 'E', 'GAC': 'D', 'GAG': 'E', 'GAT': 'D',
    'GCA': 'A', 'GCC': 'A', 'GCG': 'A', 'GCT': 'A', 'GGA': 'G', 'GGC': 'G',
    'GGG': 'G', 'GGT': 'G', 'GTA': 'V', 'GTC': 'V', 'GTG': 'V', 'GTT': 'V',
    'TAA': '*', 'TAC': 'Y', 'TAG': '*', 'TAT': 'Y', 'TCA': 'S', 'TCC': 'S',
    'TCG': 'S', 'TCT': 'S', 'TGA': '*', 'TGC': 'C', 'TGG': 'W', 'TGT': 'C',
    'TTA': 'L', 'TTC': 'F', 'TTG': 'L', 'TTT': 'F'
}


def translate(long_ORFs):
    aa_list = list()
    for orf in long_ORFs:
        seq = ''
        args = [iter(orf)] * 3
        for chunk in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue='_'):
            codon = ''.join(chunk)
            if codon in aa_dict:
                seq += aa_dict[codon]
        if seq:
            aa_list.append(seq)
    return aa_list


print(translate(['ATGAGAGAG', 'AGAGAAGTCT', 'ACACTAGAGAGAGA']))
```

Output:

```
['MRE', 'REV', 'TLER']
```

The above `translate()` function uses `zip_longest()` in order to chunk every ORF in `long_ORFs` into a 3 character tuples, each of which joined into a string named `codon`, translated by the `aa_dict` dictionary and concatenated to the `seq` string to produce a sequence.
Result is a list containing all sequences in each ORF, even if the ORF's length is not divisible by 3. If you wish to translate **only** those of length 3, you should add a check at the beginning of the first for loop.

The `aa_dict` is put outside of the function, as it's static and need not be defined every time the function is running (you may pass it as an argument to the function in order to make the function stateless).